# Can't represent data in OWL format using Jena

Tags: java, jena, owl

I am trying to create Ontology in OWL format using [Jena](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hp.hpl.jena/jena), but I can't. Eventually I get RDF not OWL, which I expected. Can I ask you what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
public class OntologyBuilder {

OntModel ontModel;
public OntologyBuilder() {
   this.ontModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);
}

private void buildOnto() {
   final OntClass son = ontModel.createClass(OWL.NS + "Sun" );
}

public void performConvetring() {

  buildOnto();

  try {
      String filenameOWL2 = OntoConstants.dirname + OntoConstants.filename + OntoConstants.xmlExtension;

      FileWriter out = null;
      out = new FileWriter(filenameOWL2);
      ontModel.write(System.out);
  } catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
  }

}
}
```

Eventually I get RDF

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Sun">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Actually it should be smth like this

```
<owl:Class rdf:ID="Sun"> 
   ...
</owl:Class>
```

If anyone know how can do this with jena or maybe some other libs please share.
Thanks!

Comment: No, you're wrong. What you get is the RDF/XML serialization of the OWL ontology. Nothing more, nothing less. The content is the same. If you want to serialize the data in a different format, just do it. In any case, the content and especially its meaning and semantics remains the same. By the way, OWL API is much more convenient for OWL, Apache Jena is primarily designed for processing RDF.

Comment: @AKSW Ok got it, thank you a lot!

Comment: The format you got is RDF/XML, the format you're after is RDF/XML-ABBREV. The difference is only style.

Comment: @Ignazio Thanks it works!